# github desktop app failing to install

Tags: github, installation, clickonce

im having an issue with the github desktop application, i had it installed before but i had to uninstall it because it didnt worked well, so now im trying to install it again and it doesnt install like the first time i installed it

here its what it says

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.3.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.51641'
Setting value '4.5.51641 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.51641 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 4.5', phase BuildList
Looking up path for special folder 'WindowsFolder'
Running check with folder 'C:\Windows\System32' and file 'msi.dll'
Attempting to find file 'C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll'
File version is '5.0.9600.17198'
Setting value '5.0.9600.17198 {version}' for property 'VersionMsiDll'
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 4.5':
Property: [VersionMsiDll] = 5.0.9600.17198 {version}
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 4.5' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application'.
```

i already tried clicking:

```
http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
```

inside a browser and downloading the github.application but it says that it cant be downloaded using the clickonce feature and that i have to contact the support team

i already tried turning windows firewall and my antivirus, im getting stressed because i work with my windows ide pycharm and i cant commit my work done today, already searched for answers everywhere and still cant make it work

pd: english is not my first language i hope u can understand me, and thanks for your help!

Comment: ok guys i fixed it, i made another account inside my computare, gave it administrator privileges and tried to install github again and it workd

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this was caused by a process locking one of the directories in Temporary Internet Files. This was discovered by using the Sysinternals Process Monitor and Handle tools.

Once the handle was located, I was able to force it closed, allowing the installation to succeed. (Rebooting would also have resolved the problem.)